# Python how do i find second connections?

Tags: python, class, methods

A's connections are B, C, D, and E. A's second connections (the people who are connected to A's connections but not directly to A) are F and G. H is the third connection of A and should not be returned. A's get_second_connections(self) method should return a set containing F and G. Can you give me some hint for this question?
I have all connection in a set, and init method gets the name and connection. The add connection method store name in set. How can I find get_second_connection?

```
connections = sets
def add_connection(self, other):

    self.connections.add(other)
```

Comment: To get an answer for your question, you need to give a lot more background. What do `A`-`H` mean? I'm assuming they're objects of some class, but you've not named the class or described what its purpose is. Where exactly are you creating your `connections` variable? If it's at the top level of the class, then all your instances are sharing the same `set` instance, which may be problematic. But we can't know for sure, since you've shown us so little of your code, and explained almost nothing.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

I'll keep this at a low level of technology; you can stuff this into a comprehension if you like.

Iterate over the list of first-order connections.  For each connection, get *their* first-order connections and add them to the current second-order set -- which I've called `friend_of_friend`.

```
def second_connections(self):
    for other in self.connections:
        self.friend_of_friend.union(other.connections)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see your class I'm just going to implement the solution without integrating it into a class. I'm also only going to describe the connections as below, since you didn't share your data structure.

```
sets = set([("A", "B"),("A", "D"),("A", "C"),("A", "E"),("B", "F"),("D", "G"), ("F","H")])

def up_to_second(name, sets):
    connectables = [name] + [x[1] for x in sets if x[0] == name]
    return [x for x in sets if x[0] in connectables]

up_to_second("A", sets)
```

This gives your expected outcome:

```
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'E'), ('D', 'G'), ('B', 'F')]
```

Assuming your data structure is at least a bit different from this, you'll need to tweak this solution to conform to your patterns. But as best I can tell this is a solution.